# facebook opening hybrid app in their webview

Tags: php, facebook, ionic-framework, custom-scheme-url

I am working on developing mobile in `ionic framework`, and i am using custom scheme url for app.

**Feature i am working:**

When user share anything on facebook, and when other user click on that facebook shared link they will redirected to that shared content details page inside of app if they have installed app otherwise it will redirect to apple or google play store.

**Issue:**

When user click on that shared link on facebook, app is opened in facebook webview rather than opening app itself.

Does anyone came across such issues? Or am i doing something wrong with this?

**Platforms:**

- Ionic Framework for app
- PHP for backend.

**PHP code for redirect user to app:**

```
header("Location: MYAPP://eventpage/eventID");
```

Comment: afaik you can´t break out of the webview, only the user can do that

Comment: @luschn Thanks for quick response, so any work around on it?

Comment: "you can´t". that means you can´t ;)

Comment: @luschn : yes i got it that, but isn't there something which force new webview session from hybrid app ? I am checking on it...

Comment: check out that other thread, it´s about the same issue. as i expected, there is no way.

Comment: @luschn i got it bro.  Thanks for help, i will post answer sooner.

Comment: @luschn  can you remove this Duplicate question flag,  this is not duplicated at all.   i am having issues with hybrid app and other OP has issues in javascript.   please remove flag as i am unable to post valid answer.

Comment: did you find a solution for it? it does sound like the same issue (breaking out of the webview)

Comment: @luschn : Yes i did., Please remove flag so i can post answer so other can solve it

Comment: reopened it. very bad idea to create a new thread, you should know that with your stackoverflow reputation... ;)

Comment: @luschn yes agreed, but i was keen to post answer and you were not unlocking me,  i am so sorry bro.  Deleted that duplicate question.

Comment: patience is a virtue ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into `AndroidManifest.xml` of my app, I found the following preference:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

And i read [Android Document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) and found below lines there.

> As shown in the table below, the modes fall into two main groups, with
>   "standard" and "singleTop" activities on one side, and "singleTask"
>   and "singleInstance" activities on the other. An activity with the
>   "standard" or "singleTop" launch mode can be instantiated multiple
>   times.

So i changed my **Manifest** as below and its working fine.

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleInstance"
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```